# How can I create a predicate expression tree if the member involved is not known at compile-time?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have an expression I need write for a predicate:

```
.Where(e => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double?) e.Number).Contains("6")))
```

However, the member that I want to test (`.Number` in the example) is not known at compile-time (it will be a `string` parameter).

I tried:

```
.Where(string.Format(
      "SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double?){0}).Contains(@0)", field), value);
```

But that did not work. How can I create the predicate in this case?

Comment: What happens currently? What is wrong with the first line that you have... i.e. why are you trying *anything*? What is the *problem* with the first line? And what is the type of `e.Number` ?

Comment: e.Number - int. I need predicate, I don't have name field

Comment: why don't you start by explaining, in sentences, what you're trying to achieve. Also, off-topic, I lolled at "why are you trying anything".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the member-name (`Number` in this example) is not known at compile-time, you will have to build the expression tree manually, for example:

```
static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildPredicate<T>(
    string fieldName, string containsValue)
{
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
    var str = Expression.Call(typeof(SqlFunctions), "StringConvert", null,
        Expression.PropertyOrField(arg, fieldName));
    var contains = Expression.Call(str, "Contains", null,
        Expression.Constant(containsValue, typeof(string)));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(contains, arg);
}
```

with usage:

```
var predicate = BuildPredicate<Foo>("Number", "6");
var filtered = data.Where(predicate);
```